# How to add default values to handsontable React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I need to know how can I add default values to newly created rows which created with context menu in Handsontable react. It's on the documentation, but it's in vanilla js. But I need to do this on Handsontable React.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in React based on Handsontable documentation sample from here: https://handsontable.com/docs/row-prepopulating/

https://jsfiddle.net/js_ziggle/ydv8k1hq/

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HotTable } from '@handsontable/react';
import { registerAllModules } from 'handsontable/registry';

// register Handsontable's modules
registerAllModules();

const templateValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const hotData = [
  ['', 'Tesla', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
  ['2017', 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ['2018', 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ['2019', 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

const App = () => {

function isEmptyRow(instance, row) {
var rowData = instance.countRows();

for (var i = 0, ilen = rowData.length; i < ilen; i++) {
  if (rowData[i] !== null) {
    return false;
  }
}

return true;
}

function defaultValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
const args = arguments;

if (args[5] === null && isEmptyRow(instance, row)) {
  args[5] = templateValues[col];
  td.style.color = '#999';

} else {
  td.style.color = '';
}

Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, args);
}

const cellsFunc = function(row, col, prop) {
const cellProperties = {};

cellProperties.renderer = defaultValueRenderer;

return cellProperties;
}

const beforeChangeFunc = function(changes) {
const instance = this;
const columns = instance.countCols();
const rowColumnSeen = {};
const rowsToFill = {};

for (let i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
  // if oldVal is empty
  if (changes[i][2] === null && changes[i][3] !== null) {
    if (isEmptyRow(instance, changes[i][0])) {
      // add this row/col combination to the cache so it will not be overwritten by the template
      rowColumnSeen[changes[i][0] + '/' + changes[i][1]] = true;
      rowsToFill[changes[i][0]] = true;
    }
  }
}

for (var r in rowsToFill) {
  if (rowsToFill.hasOwnProperty(r)) {
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      // if it is not provided by user in this change set, take the value from the template
      if (!rowColumnSeen[r + '/' + c]) {
        changes.push([r, c, null, templateValues[c]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
}

const onAfterInit = function() {
this.loadData(hotData);
}

return (
<div>
  <HotTable
    data={hotData}
    cells={cellsFunc}
    beforeChange={beforeChangeFunc}
    colHeaders={true}
    rowHeaders={true}
    contextMenu={true}
    height='auto'
    startRows='8'
    startCols='5'
    minSpareRows='1'
    licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation"
    afterInit={onAfterInit}
  />
</div>
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('example1'));
```